# AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner online exam rules and regulation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rules

I am planning an online AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner exam. I don't know the rules.

1. Is possible to check online help from AWS help documentation during the exam?
2. Is possible to check any written notes?
3. Is possible to use multiple monitors during the exam?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not in line with the type of content that StackOverflow provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to check online help from AWS help documentation during
> the exam?

No

> Is possible to check any written notes?

No

> Is possible to use multiple monitors during the exam?

Depends on the proctoring provider, for example in PearsonVUE it wasn't permitted. You also have to take the exam on their own software which requires to close every single application and if you attempt to minimize, switch context or open some other application then the exam will be cancelled.

Additionally, you're recorded both video and audio throughout the whole exam with an instructor watching you which can also cancel the exam immediately if he notices you're cheating or doing something suspicious, you cannot even stand from your chair during the exam.

So yes, it's very strict against cheating.